# Android - Start a Random Activity, but no repetiiton?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, random

So I I can create a random activity by using a Random Number generator, But What I want is if the user goes to activity 2 then the user should not be able to go back to activity 1 where the user already had been.

I have 10 activities and on every activities there should be a random number generator so the user goes to a random activity.

Example:

```
Act.1 ---> Act. 3
Act.3 ---> Act. 9
Act.9 ---> Act. 2
Act.2 ---> Act. 6
```

Note: So from Activity 2 the user should not be able to go back to a previous activity.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is pass around extras in a bundle. 
http://miragemiko.wordpress.com/2010/03/20/android-using-bundle-for-sharing-variables/

In this case, you can pass your strings around as keys in the bundle with the Intents that you use to jump around Activities, and therefore be able to ensure that you will never repeat activities.

Comment: But I don't understand the last part you said, How can i do that,?
Can you put this in code? then i will accept your answer!!

Comment: So you notice how you can put things in a bundle:  
`Bundle bundle = new Bundle();  `
`bundle.putString(“myValue“, myValue);  `

So a really bad way of doing this (inefficient) is to do something like put "1", "2", etc. in place of "myValue", depending on which random you have tried to do, and then you can do something like "visited" in place of the second myValue, so that you can tell what is visited and what is not. So, something like `bundle.putString("1","visited")` would then allow you to do `bundle.getString("1")` and then make sure that thing is equal to "visited" if you have visited.

Comment: I edited your answer with more details, so you can perfectly understand

Comment: could you please correct my code? because sometimes when I click on the button, sometimes its trying to use the same class as i am in,

Comment: I would really be thankful if  you could help me, I am trying to get this working since October, Please,, you are the only one who can help me

Comment: can you tell me your email address, so i can send you the entire project please?

Answer (score 0):

Keep an `ArrayList` with numbers 1 to 10. Using the random number generator, pick one index of the `ArrayList`, remove the element at that position and go that activity. Then, randomly pick one of the 9 left, and do the same until the `ArrayList` is empty.

Example:

```
// Create arraylist of pending activities
ArrayList<Integer> pendingActivities = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) pendingActivities.add(i);

// Randomly pick activity       
Random rand = new Random();
while(!pendingActivities.isEmpty()) {
  int nextIndex = rand.nextInt(pendingActivities.size());
  int nextActivity = pendingActivities.remove(nextIndex);
  System.out.println("Next activity: "+nextActivity);
}
```

Replace the `println` with your code to move to that activity.

Comment: Hi, so here is what I want for my app, in more details, I put in your answer